# How to get video height and width of Instagram video?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a way to get video's **height** and **width** of **Instagram** video without using Instagram's API?

Example of **Instagram** video: https://www.instagram.com/p/BMB8fWIjcLT/embed/

Comment: Please share some code/reference you have tried or come across related to achieving the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /media/<media-id> API endpoint will give you both height and weight in the response. From https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "video",
        "videos": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_102.mp4",
                "width": 480,
                "height": 480
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_101.mp4",
                "width": 640,
                "height": 640
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm sorry, I just edited my question. How to get video's height and width without using Instagram's API.

Comment: Instagram uses HTML 5 video tag, which has width and height attribute even if not specified (query the DOM to get them).